A model for rhythm game beatmaps
I'm looking into the possibility of using GenAI for generating beatmaps (levels) for rhythm games. Specifically I'm thinking Beat Saber but eventually I'd like the solution to be generalizable to arbitrary rhythm games.
I'm wondering if it'd be possible to (re)ues existing language models by cleverly transforming a song data into a text prompt and then the result into a beatmap 
Would anyone be interested in exploring such an endeavour or at least provide some idaes and insights as to how I could go about it?
PS I'm a software engineer so I could handle coding and teaching custom models.
Thanks!

Generative AI sounds like the wrong tool, and trying to make a universal model sounds like the wrong goal. Rhythm games are all different, and what works in Beat Saber (a VR game based on accuracy in 3D space) won't work for Guitar Hero (which is based on timing and is played with its own special controller). With Beat Saber in particular there are also ethical considerations: If your generated maps aren't of high enough quality, players can get injured or damage property. For an idea of the level of consideration that goes into making a Beat Saber map, see the BSMG Wiki.
That being said, there already is a tool called Beat Sage that uses AI to generate Beat Saber levels from a YouTube video, and judging from the number of Patrons, it must do so quite successfully. It uses neural nets that were trained on human-made levels. While Beat Sage is not open source, a large repository of free levels is available on Beat Saver, and there does seem to be a community behind this (and similar tools) that knows the internals of how level data works—maybe look at the BSMG Discord, linked on their main page.

Machine learning and artificial intelligence is best used when we don’t have an algorithm for a problem.  Given that Audiosurf allowed arbitrary music in 2008, it would seem there already exists an algorithm and thus ML is a bit superfluous.
That is not to say that there is not room for growth in the existing algorithms or that some algorithm under the broad heading of generative AI might help.  But asking ChatGPT for a beat map feels like the least likely answer.
